# Use output from previous commands without repeating them

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

If I enter a command that runs for a long time or produce a lot of output, I often want to process that output in some way, but I don't want to re-run the command. For example, I might run

```
$ command
$ command | grep foo
$ command | grep foo | sort | uniq
```

But if `command` takes a long time, this is tedious to re-run. Is there a way to have `bash` (or any other shell) save the output of the last command, similar to the Python REPL's `_`?. I am aware of `tee`, but I would rather have my shell do this automatically without having to use `tee` all the time.

I am also aware I could store the output of a command, but again, I would like my shell to do this automatically, so I don't have to think about storing the command and I can just use my shell normally, and process the previous output when I want to.

Comment: No it doesn't remember the output of the previous command. It only gets sent to one place that you can decide or the default is stdout.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the output into a variable:

```
output=$(command)
echo $output | grep foo
echo $output | grep foo | sort | uniq
```